# web scraping, how to make internet explorer compatibility on Edge

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web

I'm developing web scraping in Phyton but the website from which I need to input information only works in Internet Explorer, and it's very old.

I can run the website in compatibility on Edge but I can't get the program to run Edge in Internet Explorer mode for the website to open, can anyone help me?

i'm try this

```
from selenium import webdriver

ieOptions = webdriver.IeOptions()
ieOptions.add_additional_option("ie.edgechromium", True)
ieOptions.add_additional_option("ie.edgepath",'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe')
driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path='E:\webdriver\IEDriverServer.exe', options=ieOptions)

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```